explorer.exe freezing when right clicking desktop with 2 monitors
Since I added a second monitor to my computer, when right clicking the desktop and trying to bring the context menu, the desktop and all other explorer.exe windows will freeze for ~5 seconds before unfreezing again, the subsequent right clicks won't freeze until some more time.
Sometimes (but not always) explorer.exe will completely crash and restart
This doesn't happen when I plug only one monitor, it can be either one of the two.
Specs :

OS : Windows 10 22H2 Build 19045.4529
Last cumulative update : KB5039211
Old monitor : LG 24MP60G-B, 1920x1080 @ 75hz
New monitor : Asus vg27aq1a, 2560x1440 @ 144hz
Gpu : Nvidia geforce 3060
Driver version : 555.99

How can I even diagnosis this problem?
EDIT: Attaching windbg to explorer.exe, the hang on right click happend before this:
ModLoad: 00000000`73340000 00000000`739ad000   C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispig.inf_amd64_cc569e59ca39c5fe\nvui.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffa`2eb30000 00007ffa`2ebd5000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
ModLoad: 00007ffa`35bd0000 00007ffa`35bd7000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`743a0000 00000000`7453d000   C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispig.inf_amd64_cc569e59ca39c5fe\NVXDBat.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`73160000 00000000`73338000   C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispig.inf_amd64_cc569e59ca39c5fe\nvxdplcy.dll


What build of Windows 10 are you using exactly? What was the last cumulative update that was installed? If you disconnect the second monitor does the behavior continue to happen? What Nvidia drivers do you have installed? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment with unformatted information. Be sure you set the refresh rate to 75Hz on both monitors You won’t be unable to set one to 144Hz and the other to 75Hz

@Ramhound Why would I set my 144Hz monitor to 75? It is running fine at 144 right now along the second monitor

In your question you have stated that File Explorer is crashing when you have two monitors connected. One monitor is connected at 75Hz refresh rate while the other is configured at a 144Hz refresh rate. My suggestion and potential answer to your question is that you should set both monitors to the same refresh rate.

I tried setting both at the same refresh rate, same problem

If you prevent all third-party soft from automatically starting except for the required Nvidia drivers does File Explorer crash? You can use AutoRuns to accomplish this task.
